# The utility of HorsePower vs Torque

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, acceleration, torque, units

All vehicles

- have only 1 gear
- Final-drives allow peak RPM (HP) at red line = 35 MPH
- Wheel-sizes are equal
- Tires have perfect traction (yet, no rolling resistance, etc)
- Goal: isolate all variables except acceleration & speed.

Which vehicle would reach 35 fastest?
Which vehicle would experience greater acceleration (G):

- Constant (flat) Torque: 200 lb-ft through  5,252 RPM (200 HP)
- Constant (flat) Torque: 100 lb-ft through 10,504 RPM (200 HP)
- Constant (flat) Torque: 100 lb-ft through 15,756 RPM (300 HP)

Answer (score 1):

> Which vehicle would experience greater acceleration (G)

The acceleration is given by the force at the road. The force at the road is in turn specified by taking the power and dividing by the speed. So the one with the greatest power will have the greatest acceleration.

If the wheels are all the same size (and no loss of traction) then the road force is proportional to the wheel torque. But the wheel torque is not the same as the engine torque. In particular, in this scenario each car will have different gearing and that gearing is what makes the difference. As a result of the gearing, the engine with the greatest engine power will have the greatest road force and wheel torque, even though it is not the engine with the greatest engine torque.

By the way, this is a very artificial scenario, so please do not post this to some gearhead website claiming that this is the definitive answer to one of the perpetual power vs. torque discussions there. It is easy to come up with scenarios where the car with the highest engine torque accelerates faster. What matters is the force at the road, and that is not directly linked to any single engine specification. So that whole debate is pointless because it literally argues about the wrong thing. It is not about either engine torque or engine power, it is only about road force.

Comment: • I made 'best efforts' to isolate variables to disambiguate HP v TQ. 

• Equal TQ + Car speeds (@35MPH) requires different FDR.

• FDR is my only idea to compare TQ & HP utilities at equal speeds.

• Perhaps help redefine my rules to minimize the caveats / air resist., etc? 

• Remember, my hypothetical cars (A, B, C) all have Flat Torques 'curves':

• A: 200 ft-lb max RPM:   5,252 RPM (200 HP)

• B: 100 ft-lb  max RPM: 10,504 RPM (200 HP)

• FDR obviously must be double in car B to hit 17.5 MPH at 5,252 RPM

• As I'm aware [wheel TQ] defines acceleration & is why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1):

Neglecting air resistance and other forms of drag the general expression for acceleration as a function of engine power (regardless of gearing etc) is

$$ a = \frac{P}{m\, v} \tag{1}$$

<sub>Note: All quantities must be in SI units.</sub>

If two cars produced the same amount of power at the same speed, for example, 200 hp at 35 mph, then both cars would accelerate the same amount to that speed, and the time it took would be

$$ t = \int \frac{1}{a}\,{\rm d}v =  \frac{v}{a} \tag{2} $$

In your case, the fastest would be the one producing the most power (3rd option). But in general, since gearing is different for cars the highest acceleration is by the car with the highest power to *i*-th gear speed

$$ a = \frac{1}{m} \left( \frac{P_i}{v_i} \right) $$

To confirm the above, note that assuming torque is constant up to redline, then power produces is strictly proportional to the speed of the vehicle

$$ P = \lambda_i v $$

with the proportionality constant $\lambda_i$ fixed for each gear and each car. The corresponding acceleration is thus

$$ a = \frac{P}{m \,v} = \frac{1}{m} \lambda_i \tag{3} $$

From what you saw above $\lambda_i = \frac{P_i}{v_i}$ for each gear.  If you specify that a car makes $P = 200\,{\rm hp} = 149200 \, {\rm W}$ of power at exactly $v = 35\,{\rm mph} = 15.681\,{\rm m s^{-1}}$ then the proportionality constant is $$\boxed{\lambda_1 = \frac{149200}{15.681} = 9514.67\,{\rm N}}$$

For the 3rd option, the proportionality constant is

$$\boxed{\lambda_1 = \frac{223800}{15.681} = 14272.0 \,{\rm N}}$$

It is interesting to note that the units of $\lambda$ are that of a force, which makes sense from $a = \frac{\lambda}{m}$ we saw earlier. You can interpret the force, as the tractive force applied to the wheels due to the engine torque. It is essentially the torque at the wheels divided by the tire radius.

---

Using the above you can be a little more refined with the choice of a torque curve. For example, if the top of the gear is $v_i$ and peak torque is $T_{\rm max}$ then use

$$ T = T_{\rm max}  \left( \tfrac{1}{2} + \tfrac{ u  (3  u + 1)  (16 - 15  u) }{ 24} \right) $$

where the ratio $u=v / v_i$ indicates how close you are to redline. Peak torque occurs at $u= \tfrac{2}{3}$ and peak power at $u=0.851$. Note that peak power is $P_{\rm max} = 0.77233 T_{\rm max} \omega_{\rm max}$ where $\omega_{\rm max}$ is the rpm limit (radians per second).

The torque curve looks like this

[image: fig1]

where $f = T / T_{\rm max}$

and the power curve is

[image: fig2]

where $p = P / P_{\rm max}$

Using this torque curve, the time to reach end of 1st gear is

$$ t = 0.977 \frac{m v_i^2}{P_{\rm max}} $$

again showing that power to weight ratio is the dominant factor.